# Spring Testing - WebTestClient Could not autowire. No beans of 'WebTestClient' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, intellij-idea

I want to use WebTestClient in my tests. works like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void webtestClient () {
        assertNotNull(webTestClient);
    }
}
```

But now I want to inject WebTestClient into a helper class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private Helper helper;

    @Test
    public void webtestClient () {
        helper.check();
    }
}

@Component
public class Helper {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    public void check() {
        assertNotNull(webTestClient);
    }
}
```

Works, too. But Intellij is showing an error:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'WebTestClient' type found. more...
>   (Strg+F1)

New info: The test runs fine in Intellij, but not when running with maven.

Here is a test project with the problem:
https://github.com/kicktipp/demo

How can I use WebTestClient on my Helper class?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205789

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth - I was able to fix this by simply specifying the `AutoConfigureWebTestClient` annotation explicitly:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class MyTestClass {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build webTestClient before use it in tests
Use below, it will work

```
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(this.context).build();
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If the field is autowired, why does it have to be assigned manually? Either one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @knittl that was the bug in spring boot version at that time, we have to manually bind the context to make it work. this answer might not relevant now.